# react-native-sound no sound from Android (only Genymotion emulator)

Tags: react-native-sound

I've added the code to play sounds in my react native app.

I've tried specifying the audio file location in various ways:

```
    const soundInfo =
      {
        url: require('./sound.wav'),
      }
```

with:

```
    new Sound(soundInfo.url, error => callback(error, sound));
```

and:

```
    const soundInfo =
      {
        url: 'sound.wav',
      }
```

with:

```
    const sound = new Sound(soundInfo.url, Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, error => callback(error, sound));
```

Everything works fine in the Gemymotion Android emulator, but not when the same app is installed on a physical phone.

The docs:
https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound

Say:

> Android: Save your sound clip files under the directory
>   android/app/src/main/res/raw. Note that files in this directory must
>   be lowercase and underscored (e.g. my_file_name.mp3) and that
>   subdirectories are not supported by Android.

I've tried putting the audio files everywhere, but no sounds are played.

Is there a way to check where they need to be?
Why is it working on the emulator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've done some tests, I put here my findings just in case someone needs more clarity.

Having the audio files referenced this way:

```
const soundInfo =
  {
    url: require('./sound.wav'),
  }
```

They need to be placed in the same directory as the .js file using them. This will work on an emulator and on the actual device.
I didn't use the directory android/app/src/main/res/raw.
I didn't use the Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE option either as it wasn't working, so I went for the first option with require().